# Google Actions: open/redirect to different voice app

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

From my Google Actions voice app, can I redirect the user to a different voice app?

I have multiple Google Actions projects and would like to create one that shows an overview of the others and can redirect the user, on request. However, I cannot find a way to launch an external intent from my Google Actions code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the platform does not provide a way for an action to automatically redirect the user to another action. The best you could do is exit the conversation with a hint ie., "To use this action say, 'Hey Google, talk to action name'".